# How to group a object list into a map and select the first object of different type for each key using java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream, collectors

I have data like: `List<Object1> list1`.

I need to convert it to `Map<String, Object2> map1`.

Code below

```
map1=list1.stream()    
.collect(Collectors  
.groupingBy(Object1::getCity,Collectors  
.mapping(p -> new Object2(p.getvalue1(),p.getvalue2(),p.getvalue3()),
```

here I want to get the first(based on any user defined method) item of Object1 type corresponding to each key));

e.g.

```
[
 {name:a,roll:2,id:3,age:24,city:goa},  
 {name:b,roll:3,id:3,age:24,city:Delhi},  
 {name:c,roll:2,id:1,age:27,city:goa}
]
```

Result:

```
{  
  id=3:{name:a,city:goa},
  id=1:{name:c,city:goa} 
}
```

Comment: look for using `Collectors.toMap` instead of grouping.

Comment: seems using `toMap` collectors is appropriate. `list1.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Object1::getCity,p->new Object2(p.getvalue1(),p.getvalue2(),p.getvalue3()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` and define the merge function to take first one for each key.

```
Map<String, Object2> map = 
     list1.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object1::getCity,
                          p -> new Object2(p.getvalue1(),p.getvalue2(),p.getvalue3())
                          (a, b) -> a));
```

Comment: Thanks, although if I need to contain the no of object corresponding to each key in one of the variable in Object2, will be it possible in single iteration? Currently I am managing with two iteration by saving the count on first iteration in a map and then using that map while object creation of type 2 in the second iteration.

Comment: Yes possible first collect as list for key then make pair of total element and count.